# Conditions for $A^2-B^2=(A+B)(A-B)$ to be true

Tags: matrices

I know square matrices are not communicative $AB$ not equal $BA$ because matrix multiplication is not commutative. would the answer simply be the matrices cannot be square? For example a 2x2 and 2X1 will be true. Am I being simplistic?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What, exactly, are you asking?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you meant *commutative* where you typed *communicative*

Comment: @KentaS he is asking when the relationship in the title holds.

Comment: @RodrigoPizarro Yes, I see that, but what are $A$ and $B$? He starts talking about 2x2 and 2x1, so...?

Comment: The expressions $A^2-B^2$ and $(A-B)(A+B)$ only makes sense if $A,B$ are square matrices. Additionally, the two expressions need not be equal if $A,B$ are 2-by-2 (let alone larger).

Comment: In any ring, $A^2-B^2=(A+B)()

Answer (score 1):

A sufficient condition for $AB=BA$ is that $A$ and $B$ are [Simultaneously diagonalizable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization) With this condition, the relationship is true.

Comment: What about $A=\pmatrix{ 1&1\\0&1}$ and $B= \pmatrix{1&2\\0&1}$?

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's expand the RHS,

$$(A+B)(A-B)=A^2+BA-AB-B^2$$

Hence for it to be equal to $A^2-B^2$, we require $BA-AB=0$, that is $BA=AB$.

Remark: regarding the size, we need $A$ and $B$ to be of the same size (or we can't add them) and square matrices (or we can't square them).

Comment: we need $AB=BA$.